# foreach checkbox in gridview Header template

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a dynamic gridview, the header has multiple checkboxes. Is there a way I can get the checkbox individually to do something like the following:

```
protected void gvUsers_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            foreach (CheckBox cb in e.Row.Controls) //<- is there something like this?
            {
                cb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SelectAll(this);");
            }
        }
   }
```

I can't do

```
e.Row.FindControl("checkboxID");
```

because the ID is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var allCheckBoxes = e.Row.Cells.Cast<DataControlFieldCell>()
    .SelectMany(c => c.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>());
foreach (CheckBox cb in allCheckBoxes)
{
    cb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SelectAll(this);");
}
```

You need to add `using System.Linq`.

In query syntax if you find that more readable:

```
var allCheckBoxes = from cell in e.Row.Cells.Cast<DataControlFieldCell>()
                    from cb in cell.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                    select cb;
```